# Overwriting of Arbitrary memory using format string

Tags: c, format-string

I was reading an old article about format string exploit back in the 2000's, link can be found here: [Article](https://crypto.stanford.edu/cs155old/cs155-spring08/papers/formatstring-1.2.pdf)

At page 15, the author describes the mean to overwrite a variable's content by increasing the printf internal stack pointer as so: [Stack pushed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bY4fu.png)

```
    unsigned char   canary[5];
    unsigned char   foo[4];
    memset (foo, ’\x00’, sizeof (foo));

    /* 0 * before */ strcpy (canary, "AAAA");

    /* 1 */  printf ("%16u%n", 7350, (int *) &foo[0]);
    /* 2 */  printf ("%32u%n", 7350, (int *) &foo[1]);
    /* 3 */  printf ("%64u%n", 7350, (int *) &foo[2]);
    /* 4 */  printf ("%128u%n", 7350, (int *) &foo[3]);

    /* 5 * after */ printf ("%02x%02x%02x%02x\n", foo[0], foo[1],
            foo[2], foo[3]);

    printf ("canary: %02x%02x%02x%02x\n", canary[0],
            canary[1], canary[2], canary[3]);
```

Returns the output “10204080” and “canary: 00000041”

Unfortunately the author doesn't explain the reason why the stack gets pushed like this, in other terms what part of the printf procedure is provoking the override in memory?

Edit:
I do understand that the instruction in /*1*/ will create a right padded field of width 16 then write the number of written bytes (16) to the address of foo[0].
The question is why does it overwrite to the adjacent memory? You would normally think that it would only write on the address of foo[0] which is one byte not 4.

Comment: Please refer to the speficication and your understanding of the "%n" part to clarify where your problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code has undefined behavior and is invalid.

Anyway, the statement:

```
printf ("%16u%n", 7350, (int *) &foo[0]);
```

is basically doing:

```
*(int *)&foo[0] = 16;
```

The biggest issue is with the last one:

```
printf("%128u%n", 7350, (int *) &foo[3]);
```

it's doing:

```
*(int *)&foo[3] = 128;
```

but `foo[3]` is an unsigned char. Assuming `sizeof(int) = 4`, ie. `int` has 4 bytes, then this writes 3 bytes out of bounds to `foo + 3`. x86 stores stack in reverse order - the memory reserved for `canary` is put *after* the memory for `foo`. The stack memory looks like this:

```
   <-- foo ---><--- canary ----->
   [0][1][2][3][0][1][2][3][4][5]
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
                 storing (int)128 here in **little endian**
```

Because x86 is little endian, `foo[3]` is assigned the value of `128`, and `canary[0..2]` are zeroed (because `128 = 0x00000080`).

You can do:

```
// I want it to print 0xDEAD
// I swap bytes for endianess I get 0xADDE
// I then shift it left by 8 bytes and get 0xADDE00
// 0xADDE00 = 11394560
// The following printf will do foo[3] = 0x00
// but also: canary[0] = 0xDE, canary[1] = 0xAD and canary[2] = 0x00
fprintf("%11394560u%n", 7350, (int *) &foo[3]);
printf("0x%02x%02x\n", canary[0], canary[1]);
// will output 0xDEAD
```

Comment: Yes that's exactly my understanding as well

Comment: Also what you're mentioning already happens at foo[1], it will override the canary[0] value with 00 because foo[1] .. foo[3] is extended to canary[0] to fit the 4 bytes of an int pointer

Answer (score 0):

After reading the gnu lib c on the %n format parameter here : [Gnu C](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Other-Output-Conversions.html)

It states that %n uses an argument which must be a pointer to an int.

From my understanding an int is (edit)**at least** 16 bits long, but depending on the compiler it can be stored as a 4 byte word or even 8 in modern machines.

I will go with the guess that this article has been written in a time where compilers were already storing ints as 4 byte words, so therefore %n will promote each unsigned char pointer to an int pointer thus overriding 4 bytes of memory on each call, starting from the char address.

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. An int can be any size that allows to store values from at least -32768 to 32767. Also, %n does not promote. Printf is a variadic function and the compiler's code promotes all values in a specific way (details in the C Standard). Basically, all pointers are represented the same way, and when printf processes the %n, it uses the pointer as an pointer to int. It is instructive to read about how you can define your own printf-style functions with stdarg.h.

Answer (score 0):

> why does it overwrite to the adjacent memory?

Undefined behavior (UB).

All lines below exhibit UB.   What OP sees to  a potential result, but not specified by C.

```
/* 0 * before */ strcpy (canary, "AAAA");           // Writing out of bounds
/* 1 */  printf ("%16u%n", 7350, (int *) &foo[0]);  // Writing out of bounds, alignment issues.
/* 2 */  printf ("%32u%n", 7350, (int *) &foo[1]);
/* 3 */  printf ("%64u%n", 7350, (int *) &foo[2]);
/* 4 */  printf ("%128u%n", 7350, (int *) &foo[3]);
```